# How to make ReferenceManyField to match childs from a url?

Tags: spring-rest, react-admin

I'm building an application with react-admin and Spring REST as data API. I'm in the typical situation of having a Product object with relative comments.

In the element that shows the product I added ReferenceManyField in order to show the comments for that product. But here is the problem: according to the reference documentation, this component fetches the comments calling the comments list and finding comments that have the id of the father:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#referencemanyfield

But since my Spring REST produces something similar for one specific product:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "description" : "Description of Product 1",
  "price" : 50045.0,
  "title" : "Title of product 1",
  "additionaldata" : [ ],
  "pimages" : [ ],
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/products/1"
    },
    "product" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/products/1"
    },
    "pcomments" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/products/1/pcomments"
    },
    "vendor" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/products/1/vendor"
    }
  }
}
```

The logic is inverse, we find the URI to call to find the list of comments for that particular product.

How can I make ReferenceManyField to call `http://localhost:8080/products/1/pcomments` to fetch comments for that product?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following:

```
<ReferenceManyField source="your_source" target="_links['pcomments']['href']" reference="products"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried this, but obviously it doesn't work since there is no parent id in the comments list `<ReferenceManyField label="Commenti" reference="pcomments" target="id">
                <SingleFieldList>
                    <ChipField source="content" />
                </SingleFieldList>
            </ReferenceManyField>`

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your search url in the filter prop of ReferenceManyField, then in your dataProvider get the filter from `GET_MANY_REFERENCE`(switch case).  then you can do whatever you want